# Python crashing when updating wxPython GUI from thread

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython, python-multithreading

I have searched extensively for a solution to the issue I'm having to no avail.
I'm writing a program which has a wxPython Html Window contained inside a normal window. When the program starts, it spawns several threads which check for new images on a site, and if found they should be displayed in the wxPython Html Window. I'm doing this with a call to a function in the GUI class.

```
def appendPage(self, text):
    self.Freeze()
    self.htmlwin.AppendToPage(text)
    self.Thaw()
```

(the text variable is the html code to display the scraped images)

This function is called from one of the threads that collects the image file urls. I have tried using the wx.CallAfter method when calling the appendPage function as well as when calling the AppendToPage method. Regardless, the program stops and "Python.exe has stopped working" appears. Sorry if I wasn't incredibly clear, I didn't include sample code because the program that this error is coming from is quite large and using several outside libraries. I'm really at a loss what I need to do in order to allow the threads to update the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is simple, don't use threads and graphical libraries intertwined..

Your application will crash no matter what, unless you use the threads to gather data which the GUI fetches from say `thread.join()` or something similar, then you're fine.
As long as you try to update **any** graphical element from another thread you will segfault the application.

This is how all graphical libraries work (why? i don't know to be honest but it has to do with locks, access to memory between threads probably so you don't write stuff to the graphic card from multiple sources at once. One thing is for sure, mainly it's because the sheer complexity of the rendering engine would be a bugger to understand and maintain.. And the reward from it isn't that great).

What you could do is use `select.epoll` instead of threads to gather your data, you won't need threads to get the data but you won't lock up your application waiting for data either.

This is just to give you an idea of how you could turn the problem around and instead of giving the thread the job to call a graphical change, the change can be reversed so that you fetch data from the thread.

Another way is simply to give the thread a local variable of mainWindow such as `self.data` and just update your graphical element to `self.htmlwin.AppendToPage(self.data)` for each render sequence.

```
class mainWindow():
    def __init__(self):
        self.thread = start_thread('http://google.com')
    def appendPage(self, text):
        self.Freeze()
        self.htmlwin.AppendToPage(text)
        self.Thaw()
    def run(self):
        while self.alive:
            self.append(self.thread.data)
            self.render()
```